# Unity Can not change the position of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        print(this.transform.position);
        print(GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().player.transform.position);
        GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>().player.transform.position = this.transform.position;
    }
}
```

This script is on a gameobject in my level. It runs when the level is loaded up as the print returns the spawn point's correct. However, the player object does not change position, it stays in the same spot. The second print also works and correctly returns the players current position when the scene changes.

I've never had any issues with this before. The only thing I can think of is that the player is set to DontDestroyOnLoad when it is created, but that shouldn't be affecting it right?

Comment: The print isn't there to stay. Its only there to test that the values are correct

Comment: Is there anything else setting the position?

Comment: oh wait you may be on to something. Its possible the playercontroller may be interfering with the the spawn change. I'll have to check it once I get back from school

Answer (score 0):

```
void Awake()
    {
        GameManager gm = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
        GameObject player = gm.player;
        player.transform.position = this.transform.position;
    }
```

Turns out it was due to the scene not being loaded yet. Instead of Start, I changed it to Awake so it waited for all the scene objects to be loaded.